# Free Editable Grid Component For Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, grid

I've seening quite a few posts on here regarding grids, but nothing specifically asking for a free grid component that supports editing.
Has any body come across such a thing? Is there a JQuery pluggin that I could use?

If not has anybody got any pointers on a good approach to writing my own (using asp.net mvc2 and/or jquery)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that the jQuery plugins, extjs, YUI etc are completely independent of the backend technology.

Answer (score 0):

[Flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info/) is very good. It behaves very nicely with MVC because it is entirely set up with scripting an d the data is retrieved through JSON, so it lends itself well to MVC.

Also, the [JQuery Grid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6) from triand is free and works nicely. [Here is the demo page](http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnet.aspx)  They also have a commercial MVC version, but the standard ASP.NET one works okay in MVC as well.